# Plotly Outputting Blank Plot in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter-lab

I have the following code in a Jupyter Lab cell:

```py
import investpy
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


search_result = investpy.search_quotes(
    text='EXPO', 
    countries=['Sri Lanka'], 
    products=['stocks'], 
    n_results=1)

df = search_result.retrieve_historical_data(
    from_date='01/01/2000', 
    to_date='21/04/2021')

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1,
                    shared_xaxes=True,
                    vertical_spacing=0.,
                    specs=[[{'type':'candlestick'}],[{'type':'bar'}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=df.index, 
                             open=df.loc[:, 'Open'],
                             high=df.loc[:, 'High'],
                             low=df.loc[:, 'Low'],
                             close=df.loc[:, 'Close']), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df.index, y=df.loc[:, 'Volume']), row=2, col=1)

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=600, title_text="EXPO.N0000")

fig.show()
```

I don't get an error message but I get a blank output. I am trying plot price Candlestick with volume.

When I try the same on Jupyter Notebook it works.

Comment: `fig. = make_subplots(...,specs=[[{'type':'candlestick'}],[{'type':'bar'}]])` Isn't it necessary to specify the type of graph?

Comment: @r-beginners Tried this also but still I am getting a blank output.

Comment: If it still doesn't show up, there may be a problem with the data. Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: I tried to run it with google Colab. The graph was displayed correctly. The version of plotly in Colab is 4.4.1.

Comment: @r-beginners I see it works on Colab also. Must be some bug in Jupyter Lab 3.

Answer (score 1):

If it works on google colab or other notebook enviroments, this might fix it:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "iframe"
```

See [this](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2508) for more details